# rAmCharts is generating strange xy-plot with fill-color

Tags: r, amcharts

I have created a simple `amCharts` in `R` using the package `rAmCharts`. This chart is simple `XY chart` for my data, where I wanted to fill the area under the Chart-line till the x-axis.

```
Dat = data.frame(x = 0:10, y = c(9, 11, 4,7,8,9,7,6,2, 2,1))
amXYChart(x = Dat$x, y = Dat$y) %>%
    setDataProvider(dataProvider = Dat, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
    addGraph(xField = "x", yField = "y", lineColor = '#058e54', fillAlphas = 0.5, bullet = "round", lineThickness = 1, bulletColor = "transparent")
```

As you see, amCharts is generating a strange looking plot, which failed to fill the area till the x-axis.

I tried with adding a parameter `fillToAxis = "x"` as below, however then the chart not filling the area at all.

```
addGraph(xField = "x", yField = "y", lineColor = '#058e54', fillAlphas = 0.5, bullet = "round", lineThickness = 1, bulletColor = "transparent", fillToAxis = "x")
```

I will really appreciate if someone guide me towards right code to fill the area upto x-axis.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add two elements to your sequence of points: the origin (0,0) and the point with coordinates (10,0).

```
Dat2 <- data.frame(x=c(0,Dat$x,10),y=c(0,Dat$y,0))
amXYChart(x="x", y="y", dataProvider=Dat2, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
    addGraph(xField = "x", yField = "y", lineColor = '#058e54', fillAlphas = 0.5, 
    bullet = "round", lineThickness = 1, bulletColor = "transparent")
```

[image]